# How do I interact with a javascript popup with Selenium or Poltergeist?

Tags: javascript, selenium, poltergeist

I use Poltergeist most of the time, but I like running the suite with Selenium for a more authentic test occasionally. So I'd like to know how, with each server, you would go about interacting with a javascript alert:

[image: javascript popup]

Answer (score 0):

For handling alert you can check [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#popup-dialogs) reference, also described [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html).
Alternatively you could try to send the Enter key to it, using [org.openqa.selenium.Keys](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html) or using the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) api.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you with alert.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().Alert();
//get text inside alert
alert.getText();
//accept alert
alert.accept();
```

Hope this helps you.